# default value in destructuring for undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If I do this

```
let { uid = undefined } = res.body.something
```

does it make sense? if uid is not present isn't it already undefined? Is the default value here is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's redundant. As [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values_2):

> A variable can be assigned a default, in the case that the value unpacked from the object is `undefined`.

So, the default value will be used if the unpacked value is `undefined` - a default value of `undefined` doesn't make sense, because it'll be `undefined` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that example isn't useful. The only benefit that comes to mind for that approach would potentially be to clearly indicate that a given property is known to be optional. That said, I don't think it personally adds anything.

The only other case that comes to mind where I might consider something like this would be a function with an optional argument that I wanted to clearly indicate as optional, e.g.

```
function doThing(arg = undefined) { }
```

This could be useful because you might not actually want to set a default for `arg`, but you do want the signature to indicate that it is optional. You could then easily pass `arg` to some other function that might provide a real value for the default.

Comment: arg stand for something? it's not just parameter? if arg is not present when I call doThing isn't it already `undefined`?

Comment: `arg` would be short for "argument", so just a function parameter. Doing `arg=undefined` in this case changes `doThing.length` to be `0` instead of `1`, but I think relying on function length is a poor design in any API anyway. Mostly it just affects API documentation by making it extra clear that it is optional. At the end of the day its a bit up to personal preference.